# How can I get a video to only loop once

Tags: html, html5-video, playback

How can I get an html5 video to loop only once?

I'm using the html video tag and my video lasts for ten seconds. 
I need 20 seconds of video playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `autoplay` to true and then call `play()` on the element when it reaches the end. Perhaps not the best approach but I think it should work, this example is using `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // set this variable to the number of times you like to loop the video
  var loop = 1; 
  // this event will be invoked when the media has reached the end
  $('#video').on('ended', function() {
    // check if we should replay the media
    if(loop--) {
      // replay the video
      this.play();
    }
  });
});
```

The markup should be something like this:

```
<video src="test.ogg" id="video" autoplay></video>
```